# xxxx.map is not a function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have api call which works fine but **sometimes** (most of the times it doesn't) it returns `response.data.result.map is not a function` and result is, it jumps out of my app (stopping the app).

Here is sample of my returned data:

```
data {
  status: '1',
  message: 'OK',
  result: [
    {..},
    {...}
  ]
}
```

here is my function

```
await axios.get(url).then(async (response) => {
    console.log('data', response.data); // sample data above
    response.data.result.map(async (item) => {
        //...
    });
});
```

Because it just happens sometimes and not always I was wonder it might be issue of api provider that can't process requests or any other reason (not sure about this thought though).

**Any suggestion to avoid that error and my app being stopped?**

Comment: If feasible, please try using `?.` optional-chaining. So, the `.map` may be `response?.data?.result?.map`. If optional-chaining is not possible, then please try: `response && response.data && response.data.result && Array.isArray(response.data.result) && response.data.result.map`. Also, please consider, if it is okay to do so, using a different looping mechansim (in fact, may be consider `Promise.all`) for `async` function within the loop.

Comment: Probably "it just happens sometimes" because sometimes the `result` property is not present. So, use optional chaining as suggested above, or explicitly check for the presence of the `result` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue indicates that the `result` property is a data structure that does not have the `map` function usually not an array-like, it can be either `undefined` or a `string`.

One thing I can suggest is to verify that the property is actually an array before start accessing like:

```
if ( response.data.result && Array.isArray( response.data.result ) ) {
    response.data.result.map() 
} else { 
    console.log( response );
}
```

Looks like the API might be returning a different value when calling it it might be an error in case you are calling the API too often, that's why I suggest outputting the whole `response` in the example above so you can debug this problem with more information in hand.

Comment: thank you will try that see what happens

Comment: seems not getting that error anymore, thank you